# следующий вопрос по django

Tags: python, django

вот мои файлы...

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    '''Theme which learl user'''
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    '''informarion learning user in theme'''
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

urls.py в learning_logs

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def index(request):
    '''Homepage learning log'''
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\index.html

```
<p>Learning Log</p>
<p>Learning Log Helps you keep track of your learning, for any topic you're learning about.</p>
```

главный urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('/', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

но когда я захожу по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000 то есть на главную страницу, выдает ошибку 404, будьте добры, помогите разобраться в чем ошибка?

Comment: 1. покажи главный urls.py 2. убери слеш в конце урла

Comment: добавил главный urls.py

Comment: когда выдает 404, там пишет ещё список урлов. посмотри, какие доступны

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 16, 2021 - 20:49:43
Django version 3.1.6, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[16/Feb/2021 20:49:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2028

Comment: я про браузер..

Comment: Страница не найдена (404)
Метод Запроса: ПОЛУЧИТЬ
URL-адрес запроса: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Использование URL conf, определенного в learning_log.urls, Джанго попробовал эти шаблоны URL-адресов в следующем порядке:

администратор/
/
Пустая дорожка не соответствовала ни одному из них.

Comment: хм. http://127.0.0.1:8000/ должен работать...

Comment: со слешом в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в файле urls.py(главный)

в строке

```
path ('/', include('learning_logs.urls'))
```

нужно было написать

```
path(r'', include('learning_logs.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

в `settings.py` переменную `ALLOWED_HOSTS` сделай такого вида:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Но это только на разработке, и то, лучше смени `*` на `http://127.0.0.1`